# Error al intentar parsear un XML con Retrofit

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, retrofit

Estoy intentando deserializar la respuesta que recibo de un servicio en formato XML y estoy teniendo problemas ya que me dice que el nombre ya está repetido, pero sino no se de que manera puedo hacerlo... Os mando el error, el código y el XML que necesito deserializar.

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'channelLevel' is already used
```

```
<channels>
    <channelLevel ref="00000000-0000-1000-0000-000000000016">
        <id>001</id>
        <name>Max</name>
        <order>100</order>
        <country>MX</country>
    </channelLevel >
    <channelLevel refId="00000000-0000-1000-0000-000000000017">
        <id>001</id>
        <name>Max</name>
        <order>100</order>
        <country>MX</country>
    </channelLevel >
    <channelLevel refId="00000000-0000-1000-0000-000000000018">
        <id>001</id>
        <name>Max</name>
        <order>100</order>
        <country>MX</country>
    </channelLevel >
    <channelLevel refId="00000000-0000-1000-0000-000000000019">
        <id>001</id>
        <name>Max</name>
        <order>100</order>
        <country>MX</country>
    </channelLevel >
</channels>
```

```
@Root(name = "channels", strict = false)
data class ChannelsList(
    @field:ElementList(name = "channelLevel", required = false)
    var channelLevel: List<Channels>
)
```

```
@Root(name = "channelLevel", strict = false)
data class Channels(
    @field:Element(name = "id", required = false)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "name", required = false)
    var name: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "order", required = false)
    var order: Int? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "country", required = false)
    var country: String? = null,
)
```

Comment: Es importante que menciones que serializer estás usando. Retrofit no hace deserialización. Esa tarea la delega al converter que le pasas como argumento al método `addConverterFactory`

Comment: Lo siento, no ví que estaba implícito en el package name de la exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema no está relacionado con retrofit sino con el serializer que estás usando. En su [documentación](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline) dice que si los elementos no tienen un wrapping parent, debes agregar `inline=true` a la anotación.

Y tambien necesitas agregarle un default value a la propiedad `channelLevel`

```
@Root(name = "channels", strict = false)
data class ChannelsList(
    @field:ElementList(inline = true, required = false)
    var channelLevel: List<Channels> = arrayListOf()
)
```